# Declared Object unable to use

Tags: java, jsp

I have declare object in JSP is not working. I have put System.out.println() before declare the object, console got show "Declare object" but no show "Finish Declare Object" Please advice i am new in java.

```
<%@page import="com.Product"%>
<%
   System.out.println("Declare object");

   Product product = new Product();

   System.out.println("Finish Declare object");

%>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that maybe `Product  product = new Product()` got an exception.  Q: Are you running this in Tomcat?  In Eclipse?  Other?  Q: Can you look at the server log?  Do you see any stack traces?  If so, please copy/paste the full error message into your post.

Comment: So what is exact issue? Do you see exception in logs? If yes please add full stacktrace to the question

Comment: Thank you for reply. Hi @paulsm4 i running this at tomcat. i checked the localhost log file no show any error message just show the print out message "Declare Object". 

hi Ivan i no see any exception log.

Comment: Show method `Product()`